# Struts dont work

Tags: jsp, struts2

i have a problem with my HelloWorld example, Struts.

> type Status report
>
> message /HS/index.jsp
>
> description The requested resource (/HS/index.jsp) is not available.
>
> Code:

Hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
        <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Hello World</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            Hello World <s:property value="name"/>
        </body>
    </html>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="hello">
            <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd"> 
<struts> 
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> 
    <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default"> 
        <action name="hello" class="com.tutorial.HelloAction" method="execute"> 
            <result name="success">/Hello.jsp</result> 
        </action> 
    </package> 
 </struts>
```

HelloAction.java

```
package com.tutorial;

public class HelloAction{
    private String name;

    public String execute() throws Exception{
        return "success";
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

struts.xml is in - WEB-INF/classes
Hello.jsp , index.jsp and web.xml are in WebContent

Please help me. Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how do you access a requested resource.

Comment: `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher` is deprecated. You must be getting a warning on the server terminal about its deprecation. You should be using `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` instead.

Comment: I mean what did you do when you got the message?

Comment: Tiny, Apache still give me the same :
The requested resource (/HS/WEB-INF/index.jsp) is not available.
I try to fix this but i cant :(

Comment: `web.xml` should be in `WEB-INF`. It would help if you provided an explicit directory tree of your deployment.

Comment: Fail again, the same message :(

Comment: put your struts.xml along with your resources,it might be happning that your struts.xml is not getting read.

Comment: add this and then try  <form action="hello" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Again the same, no improvement :(

Comment: Your action class definition should be `public class HelloAction extends ActionSupport` You forgot to inherit the class `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport`

Comment: Tiny i dont have any positive results :(
Description is the same :(

Comment: Do you have a proper namespace? Try adding a correct namespace to your form changing the plain HTML, `<form>` to Struts form, `<s:form>` with this taglib, `<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>` and also add the namespace to `<action>` inside `<package>` in your `struts.xml`  Try deploying the application properly all over again from scratch. It should function.

Comment: The message shows `/HS/index.jsp`. What is `HS` here? Is it a folder? This can't be seen in the tree structure. It appears that you're trying to access a resource using a wrong URL. Moreover, if you have web pages under `WEB-INF` then, access to those resources will be forbidden. You need to keep those pages out of `WEB-INF`. If you want them to be under `WEB-INF` anyhow, you need to use annotation based configurations using the [`struts2-conventional-plugin`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/convention-plugin.html). It assumes that all the results are stored in `WEB-INF/content`.

Comment: HS is a project name :)
jsp files i have in WebContent
Sorry but i dont understand how use struts2-conventional-plugin and namespace into package :(

Comment: I add namespace and the same error still:(

Comment: I have just mentioned the conventional plugin, if you like to use it. If pages are directly under `WebContent` then, the namespace should just be `/` that should not be a matter. It is default. By the way, do you get any exception on the server terminal?

Comment: Also try changing the method name from `execute()` to something different like `executeAction()` in your action class and also make the corresponding change to `struts.xml`.

Comment: I dont have any excepiton. I change this execute name and still I have the same issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 The requested resource (/HS/index.jsp) is not available.
```

The index.jsp should always be at the root of the WEB-INF directory. Try to put it there and give a try.

Comment: Result :
The requested resource (/HS/WEB-INF/index.jsp) is not available.

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/478642/Struts/requested-resource.       Can you check this post and see if this helps. seems same issue

Comment: Still nothink :(
I try: http://localhost:8080/Struts/login.action - The requested resource (/Struts/login.action) is not available.
http://localhost:8080/manager/html - The requested resource (/manager/html) is not available.

Comment: This is incorrect; JSP files placed under WEB-INF are not directly accessible to clients (except in some deprecated containers).

Comment: Have someone any idea? :(

Comment: @Adam What an idea are you looking? Did you post a full stacktrace from the server logs? Did you post a directory structure with folder contents? Did you answer any of my questions? No, so what do you want then?